# Why do I get react-hook warning on calling a function in an useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I have this useEffect and it complains about add not in dependencies.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    add();
}, [count]);
```

The app is a counter I but I can't get it to work. I want it everytime when counter is changed, to add to a history of changes which I implemented like this:

```
const [hist, setHist] = useState({
        past: [],
        present: 0,
        future: []
    }
);
```

and in add, this supposed to happen

```
const add = () => {
    const newPresent = count;

    setHist({
        past: [...hist.past, hist.present],
        present: newPresent,
        future: []
    });

    console.log("add count:", count);
    console.log("add hist:", hist);
}
```

But when adding or removing from the counter, despite "add count" logs on console the current count state (let's say -1), present: in history is always one step back. Also it adds zero to the past: array twice.

And when I add "add" to the dependencies array, I get a compile error

```
ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `add' before initialization
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dew-3ix3d

EDIT: Here is now a working example of undo/redo with a counter utilizing hints taken from SILENT's answer:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-blackwell-bsdsx

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of your component? It seems like it'd be easier to keep state if you just have a single `history` array and a pointer `currentIndex` that points to wherever the current historical value is (for normal operation, this would be the last element in the array). I'm not clear what good `useEffect` does here; seems like everything is synchronous.

Comment: How do I do that? I can't add all the code here

Comment: The link explains how.

Comment: I tried to use the code snipped but it gives me a syntax error  "message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 77,
  "colno": 8

Comment: Where's your `createContext`?

Comment: There are various errors with your code, especially your dependencies. Do you have eslint-plugin-react-hooks setup?

Comment: in a seperate file. I added it to the snipped

Comment: what is eslint-react-hooks setup?

Comment: I suggest you paste your code in codesandbox . You may even solve it yourself since codesandox will identify most your issues.

Comment: Even if you continue to have issues, you can post the link into your question and send a comment.

Comment: Even better than sandbox, you can use a [react/jsx stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) for the code you added.

Comment: Codesandbox never works for me, firefox blocks it: Request to access cookie or storage on “https://codesandbox.io/static/browserfs8/browserfs.min.js” was blocked because we are blocking all third-party storage access requests and content blocking is enabled. But I have added the link nonetheless. https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dew-3ix3d

Comment: That link is from the security warning in firefox.... the real link is in the question.

Comment: What purpose are you trying to useEffect for?

Comment: When I didn't use effect and clicked on (+), present was at 0 (previous state) not at 1 (or -1 when I clicked (-)). With use effect, present is correct since it runs add after render or something, I don't know.

Comment: `useEffect` was unneeded. Posted answer with history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had to change a lot. Usually I don't do this but it seemed quick to do. Here's a react counter with history;

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Context from "./Context";

const ContextProvider = props => {
  const [hist, setHist] = useState({
    past: [],
    present: 0,
    future: []
  });

  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    setHist(({ past, present }) => {
      past = [...past, present];
      return {
        past,
        present: present + 1
      };
    });
  }, []);

  const decr = useCallback(() => {
    setHist(({ past, present }) => {
      past = [...past, present];
      return {
        past,
        present: present - 1
      };
    });
  }, []);

  const undo = useCallback(() => {
    setHist(hist => {
      let { past, present, future = [] } = hist;
      past = [...past];
      future = [...future, present];
      present = past.pop();
      console.log("undo:", past, present, future);
      return {
        past,
        present,
        future
      };
    });
  }, []);

  const redo = useCallback(() => {
    setHist(hist => {
      let { past, present, future } = hist;
      if (future && future.length > 0) {
        future = [...future];
        past = [...past, present];
        present = future.pop();
        return {
          past,
          present,
          future
        };
      }
      return hist;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        count: hist.present,
        incr,
        decr,
        undo,
        redo
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextProvider;
```

With duplicate counter state

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Context from "./Context";

const ContextProvider = props => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [, setHist] = useState({
    past: [],
    present: 0,
    future: []
  });

  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    setHist(({ past, present }) => {
      past = [...past, present];
      let nC = count + 1;
      setCount(nC);
      return {
        past,
        present: nC
      };
    });
  }, [count]);

  const decr = useCallback(() => {
    setHist(({ past, present }) => {
      past = [...past, present];
      let nC = count - 1;
      setCount(nC);
      return {
        past,
        present: nC
      };
    });
  }, [count]);

  const undo = useCallback(() => {
    setHist(hist => {
      let { past, present, future = [] } = hist;
      past = [...past];
      future = [...future, present];
      present = past.pop();
      setCount(present);
      console.log("undo:", past, present, future);
      return {
        past,
        present,
        future
      };
    });
  }, []);

  const redo = useCallback(() => {
    setHist(hist => {
      let { past, present, future } = hist;
      if (future && future.length > 0) {
        future = [...future];
        past = [...past, present];
        present = future.pop();
        setCount(present);
        return {
          past,
          present,
          future
        };
      }
      return hist;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        count,
        incr,
        decr,
        undo,
        redo
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextProvider;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-cherry-oqted

Comment: Thanks. Although I gonna need some time to understand why this works.

Comment: I removed correct answer because it's not answering my question. It provides a working example but it's avoiding the problem in the question by simply removing the function that caused the issue.

Comment: About `useEffect`? That's cause you aren't suppose to `useEffect` in that situation.

Comment: No, don't get me wrong, your answer is a good hint, but in my question I had a count variable and an add() function, that supposed to mean "add to history (normal operation on count)". The counter just worked entirely on the counter and undo redo just supposed to handle the movement through the history. You simply removed the count state variable and the add() function and set counter = hist.present for the output. That works and is syntactically correct for a display but is in function different to my original where I wanted to undo redo the changes to the count state.

Comment: @Supertyp You wanted duplicate info (counter and hist.present)? Thats simple. Either way, history is recorded (past, present, and future).

Comment: @Supertyp added duplicate counter state.

Comment: Meanwhile I created my own variant. Uses useEffect again but circumvents dep issues. Also clear "the future" when performing a counter action and disable the undo/redo buttons too when their arrays are empty. Although I had to use a local useRef variable to lock history down when undo/redo is performed so counter-useEffect setting history (what was "add()" supposed to do in my orig) won't mess. Dunno if that's the best way to do it. https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-blackwell-bsdsx With this it should be possible to replace "counter" with any periodical data and use it as undo/redo in an app.